# Create new repeating index where range of each number is dependent on the index of another column as efficiently as possible

Tags: r, vector, replicate

I have a vector of numbers.

```
initialindex= c(17,  23,  28,  34,  39,  45)
```

What I would like to get out of this looks like this:

```
finalindex=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5)
```

The number repeats based on the difference of initialindex. 23-17= 6 1's and 28-23= 5'2s.

I can take the diff of initial index:

```
diff(initialindex)
```

which will give me the length of each value in the final index (6 1's, 5 2's, 6 3's). But, then I need to replicate them with the new index value 1: len(initialindex)

Can anyone help me with this?

Tracy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using `rep` – first proposed by [@gung - Reinstate Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217536/gung-reinstate-monica) but was deleted

```
rep(x = 1:(length(initialindex) - 1L),
    times = diff(initialindex))
# [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 3):

One option could be:

```
cumsum(sequence(diff(initialindex)) == 1)

 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `inverse.rle`

```
x <- rle(0)
x$lengths <- diff(initialindex)
x$values <- seq_along(x$lengths)
inverse.rle(x)

[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5
```